# Angular seo friendly urls and page reload issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

How I can make seo friendly url like this, in backend I have node server.

```
http://localhost:3003/my-new-mobile  //product
http://localhost:3003/my-new-category //category
http://localhost:3003/my-first-blog-post // blog post
```

I have tried something like this but it is not working.I will use only one controller for all above 4 urls.
Can I used regular express?

```
$routeProvider
      .when('^/([a-z])$', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
```

When I tried to like this way:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <base href="/client">
```

and in app.js

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

It show error when page reload.
http://localhost:3003/my-new-mobile

```
Cannot GET /my-new-mobile
```

any suggestion how can achieve this or how can avoid with `Cannot GET /my-new-mobile` error?

Here is my server.js

```
var express           = require('express');
var app                 = express();
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');

app.set('views', __dirname);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);


var port = process.env.PORT || 3003;
app.listen(port, function(){
      console.log('Listening on port ' + port); 
});
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.render('client/views/index.html');
    })

app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.name);
      res.render('client/views/partials/' + req.params.name);
});

app.use('/clientjs', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
  app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname+'/uploads/'));
```

Comment: server have to return everything with index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/:post', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
```

> You'll need to set up other routes as well and they might get messed up, I recommend doing something like this instead -

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/posts/:post', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
```

> **EDIT** Maybe you should change your server code like this

```
app.get('/:post', function(req, res){
  res.render('client/views/index.html');
})
```

Comment: Your first solution is good however when I reload the page I got error `Cannot GET /my-new-mobile`

Comment: how are you serving your app?

Comment: can you please give a screenshot of the console and your screen with the errors?

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad try making the change I mentioned in my edited  answer to your code..

Comment: can you pls give me some instruction how I can remove port no 3003 on live server like `localhost:3003/my-new-mobile` replace with ` 
localhost/my-new-mobile` but I want to use only nodejs for server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108073/discussion-between-atefth-and-muhammad-shahzad).

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve the index.html file for every route on your express server not just /.

For Example

```
//Serve Static Assets
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/images'));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/scripts'));
app.use('/styles', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/styles'));
app.use('/favicon.ico', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/favicon.ico'));
app.use('/robots.txt', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/robots.txt'));

//Respond to with index for all other routes
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('dist/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

It is also worth noting, that these are SEO friendly URLs, your Angular app is not SEO friendly without server side rendering. you may want to look into something like prerender.io

Comment: Let me try with this slution